# Testing in rails without factory girl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, factory-bot

I have short question but for me important. What is better. Should we use something like factory_girl in our tests or better solution is to use simply services witch we use in our system? What is better to setup initial state of our tests.

Edit:

Thanks for answer. I have found interesting blog post in this subject:

http://blog.arkency.com/2014/06/setup-your-tests-with-services/

Comment: worth checking out: https://github.com/vcr/vcr

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer in 99,9% will be: Use factories.

---

Here is just my thoughts:

It all depends on the services you are talking about.

1. If your service is quite transparent (just creates instances and assigns some fields without any logic) then you may use it in tests. Note that in this case it is likely that your service is almost a factory.
2. If a service contains some logic or it will ever be changed it is better to test it in isolation as well as the code that use this service. And that is when factory comes.